# Problem passing parameters down in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am having a hard time using React StackNavigator, and passing parameters down to a screen. I am just in the stages of learning how React Native works, so maybe this is not the best practice so I am open to other suggestions if there is a better way.

```
function SetupsStack(props) {
    console.log(props.route.params.Setup,"route is") // This has what I want
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="IndivdualSetup"
            mode="card"
            headerMode="screen"
        >
            <Stack.Screen
                name="IndivdualSetup"
                component={IndivualScreen}
                //component={<IndividualScreen individual={props.route.params.Setup} />} thought this was it but its not
                options={{
                    header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
                        <Header
                            title="IndivdualSetup"
                            tabs
                            tabTitleSizeRight={10}
                            tabRightIcon={"shape-star"}
                            scene={scene}
                            navigation={navigation}
                        />
                    ),
                }}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}
```

The component:

```
import React from "react";
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { Block, Text, theme } from "galio-framework";

const { width } = Dimensions.get("screen");

const thumbMeasure = (width - 48 - 32) / 3;

export default class IndivualScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // const {
        //     navigation,
        //     route,
        // } = this.props;
        // const { product } = route.params;
        console.log(this.props,"props are")


        return (
            <Block flex center>
                <ScrollView
                    style={styles.components}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                >
                    <Block flex>
                        <Text bold size={30} style={styles.title}>
                            Text here
                        </Text>
                    </Block>
                </ScrollView>
            </Block>
        );
    }
}
```

The console log in this component does not have route as a parameter just navigation, but this only has has setParams (looks like the removed getParams in v5 and newer. However if I do:

```
component={<IndividualScreen individual={props.route.params.Setup} />}
```

I get:

> Blockquote Error: Got an invalid value for 'component' prop for the screen 'IndivdualSetup'. It must be a valid React Component.

My syntax looks correct everywhere so not exactly sure what my problem is, or if it isn't working cause there is a better practice I should be following.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
component={<IndividualScreen individual={props.route.params.Setup} />}
```

you have to do this:

```
component={(props)=> <IndividualScreen individual={props.route.params.Setup} />}
```